# Upload JSON file to firebase storage (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, storage

I'm developing an android application that retrieves data from API as JSON,

I want then to upload the retrieved data as (JSON FILE) to firebase cloud storage.

What are the steps to do so? should I first create a JSON object then create a JSON file?

**Thank you for your help in advance.**

Here you can see the code which receives the requested data ->

```
 urlConnection.connect();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream())); // getInputStream connects to url and gets stream
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
```